# TFS 2010 Custom Build Process - How to remove CR and LF from WriteBuildMessage stdOutput?

Tags: workflow-activity

I have an InvokeProcess activity that I am trying to grab the output from (for example):

```
'sc.exe query w3svc'.
```

which queries as to whether the IIS service is installed or not.

I am using an Assign activity to try and capture the stdOutput into a variable so I can use it in the next step. The problem is it only captures the first line. The output from this command contains crlfs which I think it the problem. I have tried various ways to remove them but to no avail.

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:

1) Moved my command into a batch file and tuned it to return just a more specific result, for example:

```
sc.exe query w3svc | find /c /i "w3svc"
```

which returns  a 0 or a 1

2) Moved the batch file into source control.
3) Added a DownloadFiles activity to my template and I download the batch right before I need to use it.
4) In the subsequent InvokeProcess I add an Assign to capture the stdOutput and then check that in an If activity after that.

Hope this helps someone as I know there isn't a whole lot on this stuff out there.